# Linear fuzzy system

Tags: education, fuzzy-logic

I need help if any one can help me
How to define a crisp number or crisp system?
Whats the difference between crisp number and fuzzy number?
And if there is any references.

Answer (score 4):

Crisp logic is something like Boolean logic or what we know as classical logic. Either a statement is true or it is not: truth-value as dichotomous.

Fuzzy logic(s) recognize that truth-value may not be dichotomous: it aims to capture the degree to which something is true (i.e., it sees truth-value probabilistically). It may be the case that a fuzzy number is a number assigned to measure the degree to which a statement is true.

For more on Fuzzy Logic/fuzzy sets/ etc, see Wikipedia for [a summary and additional links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic).

In parallel, we are seea distinction between *crisp sets* (set theory in the tradition of Cantor) and *fuzzy sets* [see, e.g., Zadeh, 1965](http://www-bisc.cs.berkeley.edu/Zadeh-1965.pdf). See Wikipedia for more on [Fuzzy Sets.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_set). It seems that *fuzzy numbers* or *fuzzy number systems* are values /number system defined within *fuzzy set theory*. See more at Wikipedia: [Fuzzy Number.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_number)

You might appreciate this youtube video: ["From Crisp Logic to Fuzzy Logic by George Klir"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNmRw7V8cbI): it captures a lecture given at a Workshop discussing what some take to be "The Paradigm Shift in Mathematics."

Comment: That makes two of us! :-)